# Parse XML with Expression trees

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I Have sample code like

```
class book
{
    public string author { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<book><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author></book>");

        Func<XElement, book> parser = z =>
           {
               book b = new book();

               if (z.Element("author") != null)
               {
                   b.author = z.Element("author").Value;
               }

               return b;
           };


        var res= parser(doc);
    }
```

Which runs without problem. I tried to create parser delegate with expression tree and failed with empty class or null reference exception.
Here is how it looks

```
public class Composer<T>
{
    public Func<XElement,T> Parser()
    {
        Type clazzType = typeof(T);
        Type elementType = typeof(XElement);

        var clazz = Expression.Parameter(clazzType, "clazz");
        var clazzInstance = Expression.Assign(clazz, Expression.New(clazzType));

        var element = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "xelement");

        var clazzProperty = clazzType.GetProperty("author");
        var expressionClazzProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(clazz, clazzProperty.Name);
        var authorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(XName), clazzProperty.Name);

        var elementCall = Expression.Call(element, elementType.GetMethod("Element"), authorParameter);
        var valueCall = Expression.Call(elementCall, elementType.GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod());

        var ifExpression = Expression.IfThen(Expression.NotEqual(elementCall, Expression.Constant(null)),
            Expression.Assign(expressionClazzProperty, valueCall)
            );

        List<ParameterExpression> variables = new List<ParameterExpression> { clazz, element, authorParameter };
        List<Expression> body = new List<Expression> { clazzInstance, ifExpression,clazz };

        var block = Expression.Block(clazzType, variables, body);
        var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<XElement,T>>(block,element);
        return finalExpression.Compile();
    }
}
```

and usage is

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XElement doc = XElement.Parse(@"<book><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author></book>");

        Composer<book> composer = new Composer<book>();
        var parseDelegate= composer.Parser();

        var result = parseDelegate(doc);
    }
```

With Debug view everything seems fine but on the fly, it grounds to gravel. Whats wrong with code?

Comment: How do you call this Parser() ?

Comment: Any reason for this except of training?

Comment: @MBoros Yes. I am using SQL Broker Service to track table change events. Changed data is in xml format and i need to parse event data to proper classes for my application needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here that I can see:

1. Your variable `authorParameter` should probably be a constant.
2. Your parameter expression list should only include variable `clazz`.

Those two corrected lines look like this:

```
var authorParameter = Expression.Constant((XName)clazzProperty.Name, typeof(XName));

//...

List<ParameterExpression> variables = new List<ParameterExpression> { clazz };
```

The thing really triggering the `NullReferenceException` was the second problem: You declared `element` to be a variable inside the block, which effectively hides the parameter `element` declared in the outside scope. That's somewhat equivalent to doing the following (though the C# compiler will reject this):

```
Func<XElement, book> parser = z =>
{
    XElement z;
    book b = new book();
    b.author = z.Element("author").Value;
    return b;
};
```

The only variables that should be listed in that variables parameter of `Expression.Block` are variables that are declared in the block, and not in any other scope. As `element` was declared in an outer scope (the lambda) it shouldn't be listed there.

Comment: Doh! thanks for the picks. Really helpful. Last question, why authorParameter  should be constant instead of parameter?

Comment: Because you're using it like a constant, and not like a parameter. The 'name' aspect of parameter is just for debugging purposes. What you were doing is essentially creating a variable, never setting it, then passing it (as a null variable) to the `xElement.Element` method. If you wanted to use it as a parameter, you would have to set it somewhere, or add it as a parameter to the lambda.